# Can't Exclude or Reconnect Switch

Tags: samsung-smartthings, dimmer

I have a Smartthings V2 hub that supports my Z-Wave mesh. I have GE Dimmer Paddle Switch that stopped responding to my hub. I tried to exclude it (both just the item in question and then a general exclusion). The exclusion process hung up and it never responded. I logged into the website and deleted the device. Now I can't do anything with the switch.

I tried doing a network repair and it tries to find an unnamed device at what I presume is the network address of the switch and throws and error that it can't repair the path. To try and remedy I created a fake ZWave device at the address and exclude to no avail. This is affecting a few of my devices due to not getting the exclusion process to work. I also pulled the air gap switch out and put it back in but it didn't do anything.

Does anyone have a suggestions to help me get my switch to a state that I can reconnect it?